# Printing multiple keys and values from a dictionary object if key is found in a user input

Tags: python, dictionary

### *********EDITED*********

So this is a more complete version of my code as some people commented. What I need it to do is print any keys and corresponding values that are found in the user_tweet attribute which is a string 160 characters or less. Unfortunately all i can get it to do is print the last occurrence of a key in the user_tweet.

```
#Dictionary item

abb_dict = {
'lol': 'laughing out loud',
'bfn': 'bye for now',
'cuz': 'because',
'gtg': 'got to go',
'brb': 'be right back',
'nvm': 'nevermind',
'bff': 'best friends for ever',
'rofl': 'rolling on the floor laughing',
'omg': 'oh my god',}

user_choice = raw_input() ###Determines if user quits program


t_round = 0 #determines how many tweets have been decoded for exit message


while True:
    if user_choice == 'Q' or user_choice =='q': #quits program 
        break

#INPUT INTO user_tweet: omg shut up i gtg
    user_tweet = raw_input('Type a Tweet 160 Character or less').lower()

    if len(user_tweet) <= 160:
        for x in abb_dict:
            if x in user_tweet:
                print x , abb_dict[x]

#OUTPUT: gtg got to go
```

So the problem that I'm having is that as is, it only prints the last occurrence of a key and value.
No matter how many I put, it always prints the last one.

Comment: `user_input = raw_input('message').lower` -> `user_input = raw_input('message').lower()`.

Comment: I think the code you posted isn't identical to the code you're running. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: I went and re edited the post to show what i hope is a more comprehensive and clear representation of my code

Comment: Even after your edit, this code works. [Screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/6jq0jt/9)

Comment: I had a function that was defined in order to reprint the input with the values for keys which worked, when i removed that the code worked fine. another user showed a way I could do both the list and a reprint and I was able to work it from there. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your new code works fine for me on Python 2.6.6, so your problem of only the last abbreviation getting printed is a bit of a mystery. However there are some improvements that can be made to the logic of your program.

Firstly, you should be testing if the user wants to quit *inside* the main loop. But you have this outside the loop:

```
user_choice = raw_input() ###Determines if user quits program
```

and this inside the loop:

```
if user_choice == 'Q' or user_choice =='q': #quits program
    break
```

But since you only set `user_choice` outside the loop that test will always give the same result, so either you will `break` immediately when you first enter the `while` loop, processing no tweets, or you'll get stuck in an infinite loop that you have to press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to escape from.

Your main processing loop can find false matches: it will print keys that are embedded inside longer words, which is probably not what you want. Eg, if `user_tweet` contains "jacuzzi" then it will be matched by "cuz".

Also, that main processing loop is inefficient.

```
for x in abb_dict:
    if x in user_tweet:
```

iterates through the entire `abb_dict` for each tweet, and then the `if in` test has to scan linearly through the tweet looking for a match on the current key from `abb_dict`. Now, `if x in user_tweet` *is* rather fast since it operates at C speed, which means it's faster than scanning at Python speed, but it's still inefficient.

Also, your code prints abbreviations in the order they are stored in the dictionary which will probably **not** be the same as the order that you list them in the dictionary definition (due to the way Python dictionaries work).

A far better strategy is to split the tweet into a list of words and then test if each word is in `abb_dict`. That way, you're only scanning linearly through the tweet twice, once to split it into a list, and once to test each word in the list against the dictionary. And testing if a key is in a dictionary is very fast and efficient since it doesn't scan through the whole dictionary looking for a match. Also, with this strategy you get a listing of abbreviations in the order that they appear in the tweet.

Here is an improved version of your code:

```
abb_dict = {
    'lol': 'laughing out loud',
    'bfn': 'bye for now',
    'cuz': 'because',
    'gtg': 'got to go',
    'brb': 'be right back',
    'nvm': 'nevermind',
    'bff': 'best friends for ever',
    'rofl': 'rolling on the floor laughing',
    'omg': 'oh my god',
}

#determines how many tweets have been decoded for exit message
t_round = 0

while True:
    user_tweet = raw_input('Type a Tweet of 160 characters or less, or q to quit: ')
    if user_tweet in "Qq":
        break

    if len(user_tweet) > 160:
        continue

    for word in user_tweet.lower().split():
        if word in abb_dict:
            print '%s: %r' % (word, abb_dict[word])

    t_round += 1

print t_round, 'tweets processed.'
```

**test**

```
Type a Tweet of 160 characters or less, or q to quit: omg shut up i gtg
omg: 'oh my god'
gtg: 'got to go'
Type a Tweet of 160 characters or less, or q to quit: LOL dude brb I gtG
lol: 'laughing out loud'
brb: 'be right back'
gtg: 'got to go'
Type a Tweet of 160 characters or less, or q to quit: q
2 tweets processed.
```

Note that this code handles mixed case, and various amounts of whitespace between words, but it doesn't handle abbreviations that have a number of punctuation character appended to them. Also, if the same abbreviation occurs multiple times in a tweet it will get printed multiple times. If that's not desired, you can use a `set` to store matches and only print a match if it's not already in the `set`. Like this:

```
matches = set()
for word in user_tweet.lower().split():
    if word in abb_dict and word not in matches:
        print '%s: %r' % (word, abb_dict[word])
        matches.add(word)
```

**test**

```
Type a Tweet of 160 characters or less, or q to quit: lol dude brb i GTG LOL brb gtg nvm
lol: 'laughing out loud'
brb: 'be right back'
gtg: 'got to go'
nvm: 'nevermind'
Type a Tweet of 160 characters or less, or q to quit: Q
1 tweets processed.
```

Alternatively you can move `matches = set()` to before the `while True` to keep the matches for all the tweets, so that only new abbreviations in each tweet will be printed.

---

With a slight change to the code we can get it to *replace* abbreviations by their expansion:

```
abb_dict = {
    'lol': 'laughing out loud',
    'bfn': 'bye for now',
    'cuz': 'because',
    'gtg': 'got to go',
    'brb': 'be right back',
    'nvm': 'nevermind',
    'bff': 'best friends for ever',
    'rofl': 'rolling on the floor laughing',
    'omg': 'oh my god',
}

#determines how many tweets have been decoded for exit message
t_round = 0

while True:
    user_tweet = raw_input('Type a Tweet of 160 characters or less, or q to quit: ')
    if user_tweet in "Qq":
        break

    if len(user_tweet) > 160:
        continue

    words = []
    for word in user_tweet.split():
        word = abb_dict.get(word.lower(), word)
        words.append(word)

    print ' '.join(words)
    t_round += 1

print t_round, 'tweets processed.'
```

**test**

```
Type a Tweet of 160 characters or less, or q to quit: lol dude brb i GTG LOL brb gtg nvm
laughing out loud dude be right back i got to go laughing out loud be right back got to go nevermind
Type a Tweet of 160 characters or less, or q to quit: q
1 tweets processed.
```

That central loop can be condensed (and made slightly more efficient) by using a list comprehension:

```
while True:
    user_tweet = raw_input('Type a Tweet of 160 characters or less, or q to quit: ')
    if user_tweet in "Qq":
        break

    if len(user_tweet) > 160:
        continue

    print ' '.join([abb_dict.get(word.lower(), word) 
        for word in user_tweet.split()])
    t_round += 1
```

Now see if you can modify these codes so they handle punctuation. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It turns out the reason I was having issues with this was how I defined a function in order to replace and reprint the user input.
Instead of splitting the the input i used a replace.all function with the input and dict item.

I will have to look a bit more into set() and read a bit more into what it does, and then later into this comprehension. I went and used your previous solution as I did not want to use code simply because it worked, I wanted to read into comprehension before I go and start plugging it in!

Comment: My pleasure! It's great that you want t o understand the code, and not just blindly plug it in. :-)  A set is a lot like a dict except it  just has keys but no values. So it ignores you if you try to add an item it already contains, and lookup is _very_ fast. Comprehensions can be a bit strange at first, but with practice they will become easy to read and write.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution was correct. It should be outputting every match, not just the last. My test in Python:

```
abbrev_dict = {}
abbrev_dict['omg'] = "Oh My God!"
abbrev_dict['gtg'] = "Got to go"
input = "omg shut up I gtg"

for x in abbrev_dict:
    if x in input:
        print(x + ":" + abbrev_dict[x])

# Output:
# omg:Oh My God!
# gtg:Got to go
```

My guess is that `abbrev_dict` has keys which are not lowercase (for example `OMG` instead of `omg`), and therefore do not match the input (which is forced to be lowercase). Try lowercasing the keys:

```
abbrev_dict = {key.lower():value for key,value in abbrev_dict.items()}
```

Comment: actually, my dictionary keys are all in lower case.

abbrev_dict = {
    'lol' : 'laughing out loud'
}

Comment: would the fact that this is actually a nested portion of my program.. I am going to try to edit the OP in order to show the rest

Answer (score 0):

`user_input` is broken. You forgot the parentheses in the call to `lower`. It is actually set to the function, not the downcased input string.

Comment: But how would something like `gtg` be found in the function name? Or more precise (according to the OP), always the last abbrevation?

Comment: @Evert: No idea, really. We would need to see the whole code to investigate this. All I say is: the input line is definately broken.

Comment: I went and re edited the post to show what i hope is a more comprehensive and clear representation of my code